# Does document ready interfere with referencing external javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the following scripts are run, I get no alert.
When I remove $('document').ready, I do get the alert.
Does $('document').ready pose a problem to referencing functions in an external js file? 
If so, why?

**scriptOne.js**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    function derp () {
        alert('derp');
    }
});
```

**scriptTwo.js**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    derp();
});
```

**derp.html**

```
<script src='scriptOne.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='scriptTwo.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: You haven't called derp() in the first one, only defined it. And you need to remove the quotes around 'document'. Derp.

Comment: It's `$(document).ready(function() {` not `$('document').ready(function(){` (no quotes around document.

Comment: `derp` is defined inside ready handler (anonymous function) scope, just don't nest its definition and please use `$(document)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that javascript has function scope.  So, in the example, the function `derp()` only exists inside of the anonymous function defined in `scriptOne.js`.

Which means it can't be accessed from `scriptTwo.js`

If you remove  `$('document').ready` from the first file and just define the fucntion it will be defined globally.

Also, (as others have mentioned) you don't need single quotes around `document`

[More information on function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Comment: That answers the question.  What's the difference between '' and not quote for document.ready?

Comment: Putting document in quotes will tell jquery to search for all elements named document.  Which isn't what we want to do, what we want to do is wrap the already existing document object in jquery.  While it may work, it's doing more work than necessary.